# How to modify the title "All paths lead to hubs: the case of water isotopologues" such that it will be one statement only?

Tags: phrase-requests, titles, phrasing, paraphrasing

We are in the process of publishing a paper in Communications Chemistry, for which we devised the following title:

> **All paths lead to hubs: the case of water isotopologues**

However, the editor asked us to change the title because it does not comply the journal's house standards, specifically:

> ***The title should summarize the key findings in a single statement of***
> ***15 words or fewer*.**

It also turned out that they would not allow a title which contains  two (more or less) isolated statements with long dashes, commas, colons, semicolons, *etc.*

To treat this situation, we thought of the following form:

> **All paths lead to hubs in spectroscopic networks of water isotopologues**

but this is not really what we would like to say. The correct meaning would be the following:

> **All paths lead to hubs in spectroscopic networks such as those of water isotopologues**

but this does not sound like a title. Is there any way to reflect the latter meaning in a title which retains the witty paraphrasis "all paths lead to hubs"? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are water isotopologues an example of spectoscopic networks or a category of spectroscopic networks?  Not sure what you mean by "such as".  If they are an example only, not a category, "such as water isotopologues" is unnecessary in the title.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. The point is that "all paths lead to hubs in spectroscopic networks" (general statement) and the examples studied in the paper are the spectroscopic networks of water isotopologues.

Comment: Are your findings based on water isotopologues transferable to all spectroscopic networks?

Comment: @TimR Yes, they are representative examples which carry the general properties of all spectroscopic networks (at least in terms of "hubs").

Comment: And the fact that they are representative examples is already accepted by everyone?

Comment: @TimR If it is not accepted, then at least easily acceptable.

Comment: Then I stand by my earlier comment that "such as water isotopologues" is unnecessary in the title, which could simply be: *All paths lead to hubs in spectroscopic networks*

Comment: @TimR Yeah, that would be right in principle, but it would be good to have "water isotopolouges" in the title just for better searchability (the paper would be useful for those who would like to read about these water isotopologues). This is a request from the corresponding author.

Comment: @TimR Meanwhile I found the following title in this journal: "*ZNF524 directly **interacts** with telomeric DNA **and supports** telomere integrity*". So it seems that a double predicate is acceptable if the two verbs are connected by "and". Would this extension aid rephrasing?

Comment: *All spectrographic network paths lead to hubs in water isotopologues*

Comment: @TimR Hmm, thanks, but this is a bit restrictive in the sense that one may think it is true only for water isotopologues.

Comment: Hence my line of questioning earlier, whether water isotopologues are generally accepted as having paradigmatic behavior in this regard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150321/discussion-between-tobir-and-timr).

Comment: Actiually, I have to head out. It's dinnertime here. But I can check back later.

Comment: @TimR Thanks. I see now what you actually asked. So one can easily accept that water isotopologues are general examples, but you did not state in your title version that they are only examples.

Comment: *Water isotopologues show that all spectroscopic network paths lead to hubs*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be a request for writing advice not grammar/language advice. Asking for things to be rewritten is generally off-topic both here and in Writing SE unless the problem is that the original is ungrammatical or unidiomatic. Asking for something to be snappier or to meet guidelines (that you don't even clearly express and it appears may not fully know) isn't something with a factual answer. Maybe drop the pun?

Comment: @StuartF OK, I move this to Writing SE, hoping that it will be better received there. Before doing this, I would reject your blaming that I do not fully know the guideline. The instruction is exactly what is stated in the bold italics part of the question (no more, no less), but of course it's not obvious what the journal wanted to restrict with this rule and how selectively it is applied in individual cases.